# Expo iOS build failed: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macos, expo

`expo run:ios --device` is failing on macOS v13.3 (Ventura) with Xcode 14.3 and iPhone 13 Pro (IOS 16.3.1)

Log output:

```
CommandError: Failed to build iOS project. "xcodebuild" exited with error code 65.

Create build description
Build description signature: 9c262b4a5f0e3f3416ac516c6dd477ba
Build description path: /Users/hraschan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Gymble-fpschecusekjgzhkzpkigakmqdvf/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/9c262b4a5f0e3f3416ac516c6dd477ba.xcbuilddata

note: Building targets in dependency order
warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] Generate app.config for prebuilt Constants.manifest' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'EXConstants' from project 'Pods')
/Users/hraschan/repos/gymble-react-native/ios/Gymble.xcodeproj: error: No profiles for 'com.hraschan.gymble' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.hraschan.gymble'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild. (in target 'Gymble' from project 'Gymble')
warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Gymble' from project 'Gymble')
warning: Run script build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Gymble' from project 'Gymble')


2023-05-02 18:20:54.338 xcodebuild[76320:782550] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
2023-05-02 18:20:55.029 xcodebuild[76320:782558]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-21677/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:382
Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008110-001E2D060152801E was NULL when -platform called.
Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7fec15ca5360>
Method:   -platform
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fec157abe60>{number = 6, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

`expo run:ios` works fine on simulator